# Directus: Content Security Policy error - frame-src blocked when embedding a YouTube video

Tags: content-security-policy, directus, helmet.js

I'm using Directus with editorjs extension and trying to embed a YouTube video, but I'm encountering a Content Security Policy error that is blocking the `frame-src`. The error message I'm getting is:

"Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”)."

I've tried adding the following setting in my .env file:

```
CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY_DIRECTIVES__FRAME_SRC="array:'self', 'https://www.youtube.com'"
```

But I'm still encountering the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely a Content Security Policy present on your page, and adding another one can only make it stricter, not loosen any of the directives. First you'll likely need to locate the existing CSP, likely in a response header, find how it is set and modify it.

To fix the inline script violation you will need to add the hash of the inline script (some browsers will tell you the hash), add a nonce to the script, refactor it into a file or resort to adding 'unsafe-inline'. You should add your chosen source to script-src.

You should also add [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) to frame-src and/or child-src (frame-src will use a fallback to child-src in CSP level 3 and to default-src in CSP level 2.